Reset scroll styles (-webkit-scroll)
I have an issue with unset css styles for -webkit-scrollbar. Seems like browsers can't unset it once it was applied.
I created an example to show the problem: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lyn2m8
Initial native scrolls (I use macos): 
By clicking button "Enable scroll customization" applies styles:
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgb(87, 20, 112);
    border-radius: 16px;
}


But when I try to reset, by click button "Disable scroll customization" -- scrollbars looks strange.
Styles:
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: unset;
    width: unset;
    background-color: unset;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: black;
    border-radius: unset;
}


And scrolls completelly disappears when I also reset background for thumb:
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: unset;
}

I checked it on Chrome 131, Chrome 133, Safari 18.1.1, Safari 18.2.
How can I reset styles for scrolls?

Related to this post CSS3 - How to "restore"::-webkit-scrollbar property to the default scroll bar. If you set -webkit-scrollbar-thumb to all:unset or set auto value for all properties it should reset whole scrollbar styles However it seems it doesn't work in the recent version of Chrome

Yes, I tried use "unset. But it doesn't work in the recent version of Chrome.
